# using grep to count unique Identifiers with word boundary

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a file in the following format with millions of rows

```
KABC XXX 111 222
KDEF XXX 123 456
KGHI XXX 567 890
KABC XXX 124 267
KDEF XXX 190 478
KGHI XXX 095 609
KABC XXX 001 902
KDEF XXX 013 986
KGHI XXX 792 001
```

etc

There are many more rows but this is just for simplicity.  How can I have just the unique identifiers printed? For example

```
KABC
KDEF
KGHI
```

Comment: Why `grep`? It's not the right tool for the job. Not by itself, anyway. And what do you mean by "numbered"? Your output isn't numbered.

Comment: @Fox it can't do it alone, not even GNU-grep. There's no `grep` implementation (or none that I know of, anyway) that can print unique occurrences of random strings. You'd need something like `grep -oP '^\S+' file | sort -u`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cut -d' ' -f1 /path/to/file | sort -u
```

or

```
awk '! data[$1] { print $1; data[$1]="seen" }' /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lane '$h{$F[0]}++ or print $F[0]' yourfile
```

Answer (score -1):

use the awk cmd and sort command

```
cat file | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Comment: That will print both the identifier and the number of times it was seen. Also, the `cat` is not needed, and you could do the same thing with `sort -k1 file | awk '{print $1}' | uniq -c`.